# Trying to understand Syntactically how we are reference a Ruby symbol that's returned by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols

So I have an example I came across in some reading where we define in a rails model

```
has_many :some_tablename
```

Then later they reference it by saying

```
if some_tablename.empty?
  #do something
end
```

I am new to Ruby, so the magic isn't quite clear to me why I wouldn't do

```
if :some_tablename.empty?
  #do something
end
```

Now, I understand that .empty can be called on a number of types, Symbol not being one of them.   So, I am expecting that the answer is going to be something like....the .inspect or .to_s is being called on the symbol :some_tablename (behind the scenes) and returning a string representation which then we're calling .empty on it.

is that correct, or can someone set me straight of how it is lining up :some_tablename to some_tablename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord makes extensive use of Ruby as a metaprogramming language to perform much of the queries you can make over a model.

When you call `if some_table` you are calling a `some_table` method which in fact does't exists, so the `method_missing` method of `ActiveRecord::Base` is called (if your model extends it) and it looks in an attributes hash which is built with your `has_many`, `belongs_to` directives and then builds a query over that missing method, specifically an inner join in your case as `some_table` is a `has_many`.

Check http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/method_missing.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about missing_method and how it could be used.  So I could imagine what ActiveRecord might be doing in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the symbol ago the has_many method is simply defining a relationship, the methods that are dynamically generated by that relationship use that name, but do not directly build off of the symbol you provide. Symbols are, for reference, more or less the same as strings, except they are immutable and memory efficient (They're singletons, so they are only used once in memory no matter how often they are used)

For more about relationships: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html